# docs: missing images when using include directives (rst, sphinx)

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am generating docs using rst/sphinx and am having a problem with images in referenced files.

The `include` directive works well to bring in rst files, but I am not getting the images that are themselves referenced from the included files.

My structure is like this:

```
   /documentation
        /master_doc
            /source
                pointer_file.rst  
                    and this file calls file.rst:
                    include:: ../../doc_a/source/file.rst
        /documents
             /doc_a
                  /source
                       /images
                            picture.jpg
                       file.rst
                             includes a figure ref:
                             .. figure:: images/picture.jpg
```

When I build from `doc_a` directory, I get text + image. All good.
But when I build from the `master_doc` directory, where the `include` directive comes in, I get only the text and the image is missing in the build.

How can I fix this? I don't want to have to duplicate all my images in both directories, which is the only thing that seems to work at present.

***EDIT: Added detail to project structure above since suggested fix below does not yet work.

I tried all of the following in response to the suggestion in the first comment, and none of it worked:

```
.. figure:: /documentation/documents/doc_a/source/images/picture.jpg
```

and

```
.. figure:: /documents/doc_a/source/images/picture.jpg
```

and

```
.. figure:: /doc_a/source/images/picture.jpg
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Where is your `conf.py`? Which directory is your documentation root?

Comment: root of all docs (my git repo) is 'documentation'. I have conf files in /documentation/documents/doc_a/source and in /documentation/master_doc/source

Comment: With two `conf.py`s, each one builds its own separate documentation and treats the documentation root as the directory that contains its `conf.py`. I doubt that one set of docs and its `conf.py` can parse another set like you intend. I suggest that you merge the two sets into one and flatten the directory structure, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.  Thanks to Steve Piercy for asking helpful questions.  I had to do 2 things:

1. move all images to a `shared_images` folder, at the same relative distance from all doc projects, and
2. re-organize my project folders to make them siblings.

Now my image refs are all to: `../../../shared_images/`.
It works!

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your image file path from relative to absolute.

```
.. figure:: /doc_a/source/images/picture.jpg
```

From [reStructuredText Primer, Images](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images):

> When used within Sphinx, the file name given (here `gnu.png`) must either be relative to the source file, or absolute which means that they are relative to the top source directory. For example, the file `sketch/spam.rst` could refer to the image `images/spam.png` as `../images/spam.png` or `/images/spam.png`.

Comment: No luck so far. Edited the above with additional info about what I have tried.  Thanks!